# Want to get information about solana validators using solana/web3js

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli

I want to get information about solana validator. information like name, sociallink and other.

I tried using solana-cli `solana validator-info get --output json` it's give me excepetd result that i want but i want same result using solana/web3js

I tried using getVoteAccounts method but it's not return whole data that i want.

getVoteAccounts return below data.

```
 {
        "activatedStake": 72482165506512,
        "commission": 10,
        "epochCredits": [
            [
                457,
                68101752,
                67687783
            ],
            [
                458,
                68511932,
                68101752
            ],
            [
                459,
                68912139,
                68511932
            ],
            [
                460,
                69310164,
                68912139
            ],
            [
                461,
                69454084,
                69310164
            ]
        ],
        "epochVoteAccount": true,
        "lastVote": 199304249,
        "nodePubkey": "8A4EdAdJ5NkEH9waDUEhKay8TBGHX3RTu3NEDXKCR9ib",
        "rootSlot": 199304218,
        "votePubkey": "HQuUQmerqwvBRFo1moWgNPpcc43EJxGUQZmgrrmqA9sA"
    },
```

but I want additional data as validors name, sociallink, Skip rate and version.

how can I get those data

Comment: I found way to get those data. we can use getParsedProgramAccounts() method where we have to pass Config1111111111111111111111111111111111111 as public key.